# Maya+Python(含:OpenMayaAPI)で現在のPCのグラボ(GPU)名を取得したい

Tags: python

現在Maya上でのログ情報を出力するような仕組みを作成しているのですが、インストールを必要とする外部ソフトウェアやライブラリを使用せず、Maya単体でGPUの名前(GeForce GTX ～等)を取得できる方法を探しています。

調べた限りでは、OpenMayaAPIの「[OpenMayaRender.MRenderer.GPUDeviceHandle()](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2018/JPN/?guid=__py_ref_class_open_maya_render_1_1_m_renderer_html)」とかが近そうですが、そもそもハンドラだから名前は取れないし、じゃあハンドルから名前取るような関数があるのかと探していますが見つからず、といった状況です。

Maya単体(OpenMayaAPI, os, sys等ビルトイン含む)でGPUの情報を取得する方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授の方お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

```
from maya import cmds
cmds.ogs(di=True)
```

と記述すればグラボ情報を見ることができました（Adapterの項目）。